# Bluetooth does not work on Debian 11 Bullseye LXQt

Tags: debian, bluetooth, lxqt

I have Debian 11 operating system LXQt version, and my computer is HP 15-n220ca

I'm trying to install Bluetooth on my computer but it doesn't work. I don't know what USB Bluetooth dongle to buy here in Ecuador. I am close to Coca, Orellana. The Bluetooth internal adapter currently on my laptop is Ralink Corp RT3290.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

---

I tried what you recommended above and it says my Bluetooth doesn't have the firmware for my operating system.

Searching, I found this website and I'm just wondering if this works for any USB Bluetooth 5.0 or 4.0 dongle? https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/how-to-install-unsupported-bluetooth-5-0-dongle-on-linux-4bf34aa99fed

I am stuck. I need help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install `bluetooth`, `bluez` and `blueman` to make my device work with Gnome, maybe you want to check out if these packages are relevant for LXDE?